# How to map timestamp to date in Object mapper

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

Right now I am mapping my timestamp to date using object mapper, but this is turning my date object's date to something like this, if timestamp is 1359657000, then it's date should be 01/31/2013, but it is showing me date as 01/31/1970, so I didn't get it what is the issue with this approach.

```
public class Abcd{ 
   private Date year
 }
```

And now I get this json

```
{
"data":
{
"fromDate": 1335810600"
}
}
```

and when I map it like this from Object Mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper =new Mapper();
mapper.readValue(data,Abcd.class);
```

now the value of year is coming as 31st Dec 1970, although it should be coming 31st Dec 2013

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far ?

Comment: can you provide some working code?

Comment: It would be best to post a [mcve] as already has been suggested. It should be quite easy so there's probably a little error that we can't guess from your short description.

Comment: I have provided the working example and thing which I have tried, please let me know if you can help @az

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I really understand your issue, but in most of situations you don't want to deal with timestamps:

```
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Then you can define the format of your `Date`:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
public Date date;
```